# I'm not able to run the ansible playbook using become to start monit services

Tags: ansible

Playbook:

```
hosts: all 
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 2 
  tasks:
  - name: Stop the services
    command:   
       cmd: sudo monit_stop_all
  - pause:
       seconds: 30
  - name: Start the services
    command:
       cmd: sudo monit_start_all
```

I'm able to run this my LDAP having root access. When i tried to ask my team member who doesn't have root access getting below error. He is able to run this manually with his ldap

```
fatal: [server.va.test.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to  closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\nSorry, user aaaa is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-aarprofdidwbskuhweylzrdcftraxroe; /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-aaaa /ansible-tmp-1590785647.34-182050508855820/command.py' as root on server.va.test.com.\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

Comment: You have `become: yes`, so you do not need `sudo` in the command.

Comment: I tried that too and received same error

Comment: Check user permissions.  Does `ansible -b -m ping all` work?

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party ( as usual ) but I came across a similar problem today & thought I'd share my fix.

In my case I am using -b ( --become ), I wish ansible to run my cmd ( multipath -ll ) like so:
sudo multipath -ll

I do NOT want to switch to root and then execute.

In addition I wish to keep my sudoers file as tight as possible, the user should only be allowed to run the multipath command.

My error:

```
FAILED! => {
"ansible_facts": {
    "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
},
"changed": false,
"module_stderr": "Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n",
"module_stdout": "\r\n",
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
"rc": 1
}
```

Of course I added multipath using visudo:
%mygroup ALL=/usr/sbin/multipath

This worked fine when logged in locally however the command failed as above using Ansible.

The reason is fairly simple. Ansible wraps your command in python and uploads to the remote host whereupon it is executed in a particular way:

```
~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609501018.2236042-3982366-65719562472760/AnsiballZ_command.py
```

If you run your ansible command using -vvv you will see the process in action including the sudo:

```
EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="XXXX"' 
-o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a9398511fb -tt X.X.X.X '/bin/sh 
-c '"'"'sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] password:" -u 
root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ; 
/usr/libexec/platform-python /home/XXXX/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609502378.1193943- 
3984795-278513799191839/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<X.X.X.X> (1, b'\r\n', b'Shared connection to X.X.X.X closed.\r\n')
```

The process was falling over because my sudo restrictions prevented ansible from running:

```
'/bin/sh'
'/usr/libexec/platform-python'
'/bin/echo'
```

Therefore, to stay as tight as possible I included those executables through visudo:

```
%mygroup ALL=/usr/sbin/multipath
%mygroup ALL=/usr/libexec/platform-python
%mygroup ALL=/bin/echo
%mygroup ALL=/bin/sh
```

And now everything works as expected.